# problem with toggling active class between components in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

Hi all I have following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-framework-28nt6):

This is My `SelectCard` component which I am importing in `PackageChoose` component `n` times.

```
    import { useState } from "react";
    import Styles from "./SelectCard.module.scss";

    const SelectCard = ({ id }) => {
      const [selected, setSelected] = useState(id);

      return <div className={Styles.selectCardWrapper}>SelectCard</div>;
    };

    export default SelectCard;
```

css:

```
    .selectCardWrapper {
      border: 1px solid grey;
    }
   .selectCardWrapperActive {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

PackageChoose component code:

```
    const PackageChoose = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <SelectCard id={1}/>
          <SelectCard id={2}/>
          <SelectCard id={3}/>
             ...
          <SelectCard id={n}/> //just example
       </div>
      );
    };
```

How can I toggle between that classes ?, For example if I click on first `Select Card` component it should become with red borders, and others should stay with gray borders.  And after that if I click on second component then the first one and others  should became with grey borders  and second is should become with red borders...and so one...

Please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want only one to be active at a time, you will have to move the `selected` state to the `PackageChoose` component.

Something like

```js
import Styles from "./SelectCard.module.scss";

const SelectCard = ({ id, selected, onSelect }) => {
  const myClassName = (id === selected) ?
    Styles.selectCardWrapperActive :
    Styles.selectCardWrapper;

  return (
    <div 
      className={myClassName} 
      onClick={() => onSelect(id)}>
      SelectCard
    </div>
  );
};

export default SelectCard;
```

PackageChoose component code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const PackageChoose = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <SelectCard id={1} selected={selected} onSelect={setSelected} />
      <SelectCard id={2} selected={selected} onSelect={setSelected} />
      <SelectCard id={3} selected={selected} onSelect={setSelected} />
         ...
      <SelectCard id={n} selected={selected} onSelect={setSelected} /> //just example
   </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

- Lift the state up to `PackageChoose` component
- Add a `onClick` listener to `SelectCard`
- Update the id state , based on click
- `SelectCard` will be active based on the id

**SelectCard**

```
const SelectCard = ({ isActive,onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={
        isActive ? Styles.selectCardWrapperActive : Styles.selectCardWrapper
      }
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      SelectCard
    </div>
  );
};
```

**PackageChoose**

```
const PackageChoose = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(-1);
  return (
    <div>
      {Array.from({ length: 6 /* n */}, (_, index) => (
        <SelectCard
          onClick={() => setSelected(index)}
          isActive={selected === index}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```